# Search list and print results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to allow a user to search a list for someone's name and then have it print the other details about them, specifically I'm trying to make a hospital registry system, a very basic one, where a patient can input their name and symptoms and they are given a "patient ID", a 4 digit code to identify them, these are then all saved to a .txt file for later retrieval. But then I want the next user to be able to search the person's name and be able to find out their ID, here's my code and sorry for the bad explanation. As you can see at the end I tried to think of a way to solve it but couldn't.

````
import random as rand

def Menu():
    boxWidth = 52
    print("*" * boxWidth)
    print("* Welcome to Cool Hospital                         *")
    print("* If you are a patient, enter 'P',                 *")
    print("* if you are here to see a patient please enter 'V'*")
    print("* This system is case sensitive.                   *")
    print("*" * boxWidth)
    MenuChoice = input("")
    return MenuChoice


MenuChoice = Menu()
if MenuChoice == "P":
    f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "a+")
    PatientID = rand.randint(1, 10000)
    PatientID = str(PatientID)
    print("Your patient ID is;", PatientID, ".")
    PatientName = input("Please enter your first name.")
    f.write(PatientName)
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(PatientID)
    f.write(" ")
    f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "r")
    print("Entries to the hospital are categorised by their symptoms into  either red, amber or green.")
    SymptomLevel = input(
        "If your symptoms are life threatening type 'R', if they are serious but not life threatening type 'A', "
        "if they are mild then enter 'G'.")
    f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "a+")
    f.write(SymptomLevel)
    f.write("\n")

elif MenuChoice == "V":
    PatientFinder = input("Please enter the patient's first name.")
    f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "r")
    with open('PatientInfo.txt') as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    if PatientFinder in lines:
        print() ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good start: you read the file line by line and put the lines in an array. So, if the file would look like this:

```
patient1 1 G
patient2 2 R
patient3 3 A
```

Then the array that you have called `lines` will be like so:

```py
lines = ["patient1 1 G", "patient2 2 R", "patient3 3 A"]
```

So now we want to check if the name given as an input is in one of the lines, don't we? Let's see what happens if we do what you did:

```
if PatientFinder in lines:
    <some code>
```

This will check if the value of `PatientFinder` is an element of the array. Unfortunately, this is not really what we want: if `PatientFinder` would be `patient1`, `<some code>` would not be executed, because the string `"patient1"` isn't an element of the array.

No, it is *a part of* an item in the array! So let's loop over all those items in the array with a for-loop:

```
for line in lines:
    #...
```

Now, `line` will every time be one line from the file. Let's check if the line contains the name of the patient as a substring:

```
    if PatientFinder in line: # This line contains data for the patient we asked for! 
        #...
```

And now, we can do anything we want, for instance, print the line with this patient's info:

```
        print(line)
```

Okay, let's see the whole code below!

```
elif MenuChoice == "V":
    PatientFinder = input("Please enter the patient's first name.")
    f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "r")
    with open('PatientInfo.txt') as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    for line in lines:
        if PatientFinder in line: # This line contains data for the patient we asked for! 
            print(line)
```

Good luck!

---

Bonus: if you like some unsolicited feedback on your code, below I have some quick ideas:

- As you know, it's important to give your variables and functions good names, to keep your code clear. It's a good practice to start names of *variables and functions* with a *lowercase*, while names of *classes and types* should start with an Uppercase.

  This is to make a distinction between *types* and *instances* of that types. This rule is used very widely, so knowing this may also help you when reading existing code.

  So `Menu` would become `menu`, `MenuChoice` -> `menuChoice` and so on.
- You tell the user that the system is case sensitive, which is true. If you would like to change that, you can do `input("").upper()`, which converts any string to uppercase (and does nothing when a string is already fully uppercased).
- In your code, I see these two lines:

  ```
      PatientID = rand.randint(1, 10000)
      PatientID = str(PatientID)
  ```

  Which could be done in one line if you like:

  ```
      PatientID = str(rand.randint(1, 10000))
  ```

  (By the way, I am not sure if randint is the best choice, because it's not too unlikely that you will get twice the same number so that you get two patients with the same ID, which may be unfavorable.)
- And these four lines:

  ```
      f.write(PatientName)
      f.write(" ")
      f.write(PatientID)
      f.write(" ")
  ```

  Could be done as:

  ```
      f.write(PatientName + " " + PatientID + " ")
  ```
- After those lines, I seem to miss why you do these lines:

  ```
      f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "r")
      # (...)
      f = open("PatientInfo.txt", "a+")
  ```

  I would recommend to double check if they have any purpose.

Hope this is useful for you!

Comment: Thanks so much this has been super helpful, for the last point you made, I was following a guide and didn't quite understand it but I thought that to read from the file you had to open it in 'read' mode and to append to it, you had to do the same for append mode each time you wanted to read or write, is this incorrect, if so, could you explain it, please?

Comment: I'm happy to hear that I helped you! What you say, is true (as far as I know). But between those lines, you aren't reading from the file at all. You 'read' something from the user input, but that doesn't affect the file or your variable `f`.